# Pages get 444 when I expect them to be served

Tags: nginx

I have a server with several VHosts on Nginx.

Based on my reading of the documentation, I've designed it this way:

```
(...various configs...)
##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


# HTTP 444: non standard NGINX specific "drop connection"
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
}
```

I tested the server itself with SSLLabs, got the all-green and was happy. The server drops the annoying requests for wordpress admin, among other things the log says.

Then I decided to create a simple set of pages.

I wanted to have a folder on my host with private data but public index.html and a public mypage.html and mypage2.html, so I created `locations`in my sites-available/host_conf file.

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl on;

location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png|svg)$ {
    root /var/www/images/;
}

server_name host.com www.host.com;
root /var/www/host/main/html/;

location = /folder/mypage.html {
    auth_basic "off";
}

location = /folder/mypage2.html {
    auth_basic "off";
}

location = /folder/ {
    index index.html;
}

location /folder/ {
    auth_basic "Acces restreint";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/host/main/.htpasswd;
}

location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }
}
```

Here's where it gets ugly:

If I navigate to host.com, I get the 200 and the page. Fine.

If I navigate to host.com/folder, I get the auth request and a log `"GET /folder HTTP/1.1" 301 185`, then a 401 if I don't log in.

If I navigate to host.com/mypage.html, I get the page and a log `"GET /folder/mypage.html HTTP/1.1" 200 713`.

If I navigate to host.com/mypage2.html, I get a failure (cannot display page) and a log `"GET /folder/mypage2.html HTTP/1.1" 444 0 "-"`

From then on, I get failures for a while.

What should I look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have solved the problem by adding another block:

```
location = /folder/index.html {
auth_basic "off";
}
```